# Way to restore the data in the accidentally overwritten layer by its duplicate layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geopackage, undo-redo

In QGIS 3.10.12, I duplicated a GeoPackage vector layer. I made a lot of changes to the new (duplicate) layer and accidentally saved it. Now the original layer has been wiped. The undo button is disabled for the duplicate layer so I cannot undo the changes. As it turns out, this is a QGIS feature.

I don't have a backup or shadow copy of the geo-package.

QGIS is still running. I have not closed it yet. Is there a way of restoring my data?

Such as temporary files that may have been saved somewhere (in `\ApplicationData\` or `Temp` folder, for example).

I tried `Current Edits > Rollback For All Layers`, but nothing happened.

Comment: If the .wal file still exists it is possible that edits have not been written into .gpkg file yet. Copy just the .gpkg file into another directory, rename it, open and see in which state it is.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks a lot, it worked. I had made copies of the three files immediately after the disaster, but I was planning on restoring **all three of them**. It was a mistake. As you correctly said, only the geo-package file should be restored, not the two cache files. Please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote and choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: Please don't post an answer in the question. You can answer your own question here.

Comment: You can write an answer and get some credits. Add a link to https://sqlite.org/wal.html and warn that once checkpointing has happened there is no return.

Comment: A good idea is always to keep all original data in a folder that is write protected, so you are forced to use a copy for editing. A good concept of data management does help a lot

Comment: SQLite databases which are set into WAL journal mode can't even be opened from write protected folders because SQLite needs to create the wal file on opening so user is certainly forced to use a copy. For such data management concept it might be more practical to change the journal mode of GeoPackages into something else with a SQLite PRAGMA command.

Answer (score 12):

The original answer by @user30184:

> If the .wal file still exists it is possible that edits have not been written into .gpkg file yet. Copy just the .gpkg file into another directory, rename it, open and see in which state it is.

**Some tips:** QGIS stores the changes in the cache files before applying them to the geo-package. If you have the same (or a similar) problem, don't close QGIS. Keep it running, don't do anything, no edits, no saves, nothing. Just make a copy of the `gpkg`-file immediately. Don't try making a compressed file using zip applications, because you will receive an error message akin to:

> Cannot read the file because it is currently being used by another
> application.

Just make a copy.

Here's more information on the issue: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19489